# get values from fireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using **Firebase** in my **Android Studio** project, and I would like to know how can I get the whole firebase data (picture below).

[image: my database]

I created 4 classes

City class which contains 3 string and an AllPlaces object:

```
public class City {
private String name;
private String image;
private String hebrew;
private AllPlaces allPlaces;

public City(String name, String image, String hebrew, AllPlaces allPlaces) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.hebrew = hebrew;
    this.allPlaces = allPlaces;
    Log.d("niv","!!!");
}

public City() {}

public String getHebrew() {
    return hebrew;
}

public void setHebrew(String hebrew) {
    this.hebrew = hebrew;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String picUrl) {
    this.image = picUrl;
}

public AllPlaces getAllPlaces() {
    return allPlaces;
}

public void setAllPlaces(AllPlaces allPlaces) {
    this.allPlaces = allPlaces;
}
```

AllPlaces class which contains HashMap of Place categories:

```
public class AllPlaces {

private HashMap<String,PlaceCategory> placeHashMap=new HashMap<>();

public AllPlaces() {
}

public AllPlaces(HashMap<String, PlaceCategory> placeHashMap) {
    this.placeHashMap = placeHashMap;
}

public HashMap<String, PlaceCategory> getPlaceHashMap() {
    return placeHashMap;
}

public void setPlaceHashMap(HashMap<String, PlaceCategory> placeHashMap) {
    this.placeHashMap = placeHashMap;
}
```

Place category class which contains two strings and places hashmap:

```
public class PlaceCategory {
private String name;
private String Hname;
private HashMap<String,Place> places=new HashMap<>();

public PlaceCategory(String name, String hname, HashMap<String, Place> places) {
    this.name = name;
    Hname = hname;
    this.places = places;
}

public PlaceCategory() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getHname() {
    return Hname;
}

public void setHname(String hname) {
    Hname = hname;
}

public HashMap<String, Place> getPlaces() {
    return places;
}

public void setPlaces(HashMap<String, Place> places) {
    this.places = places;
}
```

Place class which contains two strings:

```
public class Place {

private String name;
private String Hname;


public Place() {
}

public Place(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Place(String name, String hname) {
    this.name = name;
    Hname = hname;
}

public String getHname() {
    return Hname;
}

public void setHname(String hname) {
    Hname = hname;
}
```

After that, I tried to get the data by using:

```
 List<City> cities=new ArrayList<>();
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference citiesRef= database.getReference("cities");

  citiesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                cities.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    City city = snapshot.getValue(City.class);
                    cities.add(city);
                }
             }
           }
```

**Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.win10.triplanner, PID: 11822
                                               com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.win10.triplanner.PlaceCategory
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.example.win10.triplanner.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:162)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

**IMPORTANT**
Before I create those class, I only had the city class that contained only the strings, and I got the 3 strings from firebase and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean throught " whole firebase data"? What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: An array list that includes the cities and the information about each one of them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I editted my question

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using to get the data from the database.

Comment: I added it, any ideas?

Comment: At which line of code are you getting this exception?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670955/nested-maps-in-firebase-and-custom-objects